# testcafe for api test - how to verify response code with custom requesthook

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, httprequest, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to write a sample test in testcafe to verify api response code.

Below is my code

```html
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

class JwtBearerAuthorization extends RequestHook {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  onRequest (e) {
    e.requestOptions.headers['Authorization'] = 'some token';
    e.requestOptions.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
  }

  onResponse (e) {

  }
}

const jwtBearerAuthorization = new JwtBearerAuthorization();

fixture `Fixture`
.page('http://mywebsite.com/api/example/learning_items')
.requestHooks(jwtBearerAuthorization);

test('basic', async t => {
  await t
   .expect(jwtBearerAuthorization.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok();
});
```

I am not sure how to set `responseEventConfigureOpts` to true. Documentation is not clear if i pass custom header [like authentication], how to get response code.

http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/creating-a-custom-http-request-hook.html

Answer (score 4):

`responseEventConfigureOpts` is an object with the `includeHeaders` and `includeBody` properties. To set them, it is sufficient to pass the `{ includeHeaders: true/false, includeBody: true/false }` object as a second parameter in the `RequestHook` constructor.

In addition, you don't need to write any hook related logic out of the `onRequest` or `onResponse` methods. Take a look at [this documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/requesthook/#request-handler):

> The `onRequest` method is called before sending the request. Use this
> method to handle sending the request. You can change the request
> parameters before it is sent. When a response is received, the hook
> starts preparing to call the `onResponse` method that handles the
> response.

So you can check statusCode of the response in the `onResponse` method:

```
onResponse (e) {
    const code = e.statusCode;
}
```

UPD.

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

const allResponces = {};

class Hook extends RequestHook {
    constructor (testName) {
        super();

        this.testName               = testName;
        allResponces[this.testName] = [];
    }

    onRequest (e) {
        console.log('onRequest');
    }

    onResponse (e) {
        console.log('onResponse');

        allResponces[this.testName].push(e);
    }
}

const getHook = (testName) => {
    return new Hook(testName);
};

fixture `Hook`
    .page `http://example.com`;


test('basic', async t => {
    await t.click('h1');
    await t.click('div');
    console.log(allResponces['basic'].length);
    await t.expect(allResponces['basic'].every(r => r.statusCode === 200)).ok();
}).requestHooks(getHook('basic'));
```

Comment: Passing `{ includeHeaders: true/false, includeBody: true/false }` worked fine. However i would like to assert response Code in Fixture > test. How to get response code in test

"await t
  .expect(jwtBearerAuthorization.contains(r => r.response.statusCode === 200)).ok(); "


But when I run it, it says ` TypeError: jwtBearerAuthorization.contains is not a function`

Comment: `jwtBearerAuthorization` is an instance of the RequestHook class, so it does not have the `contains` property. As I said previously, you can get statusCode of the response in the `onResponse` method. You can re organize your test code to collect responses in the hook, and to check response statuses in your test code. I've added a sample example to my answer.

Comment: Hi @alex kamaev,
I'm trying to run your example using the latest version of TestCafe & Typescript, versions 1.1.0 & v3.4.5 respectively. I had to declare 'testName' as an any above the constructor because of TS2339 error. When running the fixture the code goes into an endless loop in async_hooks.js --> emitHookFactory. Any help? Thanks

Comment: @faisalk Hi, could you please provide more details about the issue? I've checked my example one more time and it works as expected. Provide your full test code which tests some public url to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @AlexKamaev, I've modified the code now so it works. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { RequestHook } from 'testcafe';

const allResponces = {};

class Hook extends RequestHook {
  testName;  
    constructor (testName) {
      super();

        this.testName               = testName;
        allResponces[this.testName] = [];
    }

    async onRequest (e) {
        console.log('onRequest');
    }

    async onResponse (e) {
        console.log('onResponse');

        allResponces[this.testName].push(e);
    }
}

const getHook = (testName) => {
    return new Hook(testName);
};

fixture `Hook`
    .page `https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example`;


test('basic', async t => {
    await t.click('h1');
    await t.click('#developer-name');
    console.log(allResponces['basic'].length);
    await t.expect(allResponces['basic'].every(r => r.statusCode === 200)).ok();
}).requestHooks(getHook('basic'));
```

Comment: If you would like to send a request in your test and check the response value, you can use the [`t.request` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403981/reference/test-api/testcontroller/request) - it is available in TestCafe 1.20.0+.
See the following code example:
`await t.expect(t.request('http://localhost:3000/api/data').status).eql(200);`. 
Also please note that if `t.request` is called inside an assertion it triggers the  [Smart Assertion Query Mechanism](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402837/guides/basic-guides/assertions#smart-assertion-query-mechanism).